# Upgrading Gitlab 7.3.2 to current Release

Tags: installation, gitlab, upgrade, updates, gitlab-omnibus

We are running an old Gitlab Instance with 7.3.2 Omnibus Installation as I see. The Server was setup by someone who is not longer reachable. I tried to upgrade directly through omnibus from 7 to 10 but that did not work. When executing `gitlab-ctl reconfigure` I get the following Error

```
Recipe: gitlab::database_migrations
  * bash[migrate gitlab-rails database] action run
    [execute] rake aborted!
              PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
                Is the server running locally and accepting
                connections on Unix domain socket "/var/opt/gitlab/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
              /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/tasks/gitlab/db.rake:49:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
              /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
              /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
              Tasks: TOP => gitlab:db:configure
              (See full trace by running task with --trace)

    ================================================================================
    Error executing action `run` on resource 'bash[migrate gitlab-rails database]'
    ================================================================================

    Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed
    ------------------------------------
    Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'
    ---- Begin output of "bash"  "/tmp/chef-script20171203-14483-19wea60" ----
    STDOUT: rake aborted!
    PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/var/opt/gitlab/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
    /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/tasks/gitlab/db.rake:49:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
    /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
    /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
    Tasks: TOP => gitlab:db:configure
    (See full trace by running task with --trace)
    STDERR:
    ---- End output of "bash"  "/tmp/chef-script20171203-14483-19wea60" ----
    Ran "bash"  "/tmp/chef-script20171203-14483-19wea60" returned 1

     Resource Declaration:
    ---------------------
    # In /opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/cache/cookbooks/gitlab/recipes/database_migrations.rb

     51: bash "migrate gitlab-rails database" do
     52:   code <<-EOH
     53:     set -e
     54:     log_file="#{node['gitlab']['gitlab-rails']['log_directory']}/gitlab-rails-db-migrate-$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S).log"
     55:     umask 077
     56:     /opt/gitlab/bin/gitlab-rake gitlab:db:configure 2>& 1 | tee ${log_file}
     57:     STATUS=${PIPESTATUS[0]}
     58:     echo $STATUS > #{db_migrate_status_file}
     59:     exit $STATUS
     60:   EOH
     61:   environment env_variables unless env_variables.empty?
     62:   notifies :run, "execute[clear the gitlab-rails cache]", :immediately
     63:   dependent_services.each do |svc|
     64:     notifies :restart, svc, :immediately
     65:   end
     66:   not_if "(test -f #{db_migrate_status_file}) && (cat #{db_migrate_status_file} | grep -Fx 0)"
     67:   only_if { node['gitlab']['gitlab-rails']['auto_migrate'] }
     68: end

    Compiled Resource:
    ------------------
    # Declared in /opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/cache/cookbooks/gitlab/recipes/database_migrations.rb:51:in `from_file'

    bash("migrate gitlab-rails database") do
      action [:run]
      retries 0
      retry_delay 2
      default_guard_interpreter :default
      command "migrate gitlab-rails database"
      backup 5
      returns 0
      code "    set -e\n    log_file=\"/var/log/gitlab/gitlab-rails/gitlab-rails-db-migrate-$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S).log\"\n    umask 077\n    /opt/gitlab/bin/gitlab-rake gitlab:db:configure 2>& 1 | tee ${log_file}\n    STATUS=${PIPESTATUS[0]}\n    echo $STATUS > /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/upgrade-status/db-migrate-873248b1f0d3a7a5535771a3a1635803-da70bc4\n    exit $STATUS\n"
      interpreter "bash"
      declared_type :bash
      cookbook_name "gitlab"
      recipe_name "database_migrations"
      not_if "(test -f /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/upgrade-status/db-migrate-873248b1f0d3a7a5535771a3a1635803-da70bc4) && (cat /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/upgrade-status/db-migrate-873248b1f0d3a7a5535771a3a1635803-da70bc4 | grep -Fx 0)"
      only_if { #code block }
    end

    Platform:
    ---------
    x86_64-linux


Running handlers:
Running handlers complete
Chef Client failed. 3 resources updated in 36 seconds
```

I read a lot in the docs, but there are so much information, that I cannot get the update working.
So what are the required steps to get the installation to a current release and what are the critical steps to take?

Comment: As a suggestion, you could start trying intermediate upgrades (I mean, several migration versions as different steps) to previous versions, since the best approach for Gitlab is to keep updating regularly to the next version.

Answer (score 1):

In general you should not jump across multiple major versions (i.e. 7.x, 8.x, 9.x and 10.x are major versions. They contain breaking changes.

From your current version of 7.3, I recommend trying to upgrade to 7.14.x, then to 8.0.x, 8.17.x, 9.0, 9.5.x, 10.0, 10.latext (whatever is latest at the time. After each step, verify that the web UI works and you can clone/push. Also follow the logs to check for obvious errors - `sudo gitlab-ctl tail`.

If you're using the GitLab package repository to upgrade (via yum/apt) you can find the specific version/install command you need to use at https://packages.gitlab.com/gitlab/gitlab-ce. Search for a version string such as `10.1.`. Click on the RPM or Deb package for your OS version, then you will see an install command such as `apt-get install gitlab-ce=10.1.5-ce.0` (Ubuntu Trusty) or `yum install gitlab-ce-10.1.5-ce.0.el7.x86_64` (CentOS/RHEL 7). No need to repeat the `curl | bash` bit each time.